# Unity Networking between two devices not working

Tags: android, ios, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Here is what I would like to do. I have a PC / tablet which will be connected to a localhost. Than I will have a smartphone which will be connected the localhost aswell. 
The smartphone will be a 360 panoramic viewer for Virtual reality and the PC /tablet will say what the smartphone user will see. So I can choose from a list of cities / places on the tablet. If I choose one, the smartphone will view that place in 360.
What I need is a network connection / multiplayer in unity. 
Which works fine. But I can't figure out, why I can't select content on one device and view it on the other. They are apparently not connecting well?

I have a few Skyboxes with the 360 places on it and I would like to switch between them. So for the PC / tablet I've got a UI View, with a list of all places. And the smartphone has a 360 Viewer. When I choose a place, it only switches the skybox on the localplayer and not on the smartphone.

I am using the latest Unity 5.4.1 version and it should work on ios, android and standalone windows / mac